# Difference between $F[x]$ and $F(x)?$

Tags: field-theory

For a field $F$ what exactly does $F(x)$ look like? I know that $F[x] \neq F(x)$ as $x$ is transcendental over $F...$ Does $F(x)$ simply contain polynomials of negative degrees?

Answer (score 2):

The notation $F[x]$ where $F$ is a field and $x$ is an indeterminate often means the algebra of polynomials in one variable $x$ over the field $F$.

By contrast the notation $F(x)$ in the same circumstances would likely mean the *field* of rational functions in one variable over field $F$.

Thus $F[x] \subset F(x)$ is a proper inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

$F[x]$ is the *field of fractions* of $F[x]$, i.e. it is made up of quotients of polynomials. In other words, it is to $F[x]$ what $\mathbf Q$ is to $\mathbf Z$.

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken would that mean inverses of polynomials of $F[x]$ exist in $F(x)?$

Comment: Perfectly right. A fraction field of an integral domain is done for that: obtaining inverses for all non-zero elements.